# What is the first moment of ML estimator theta=n/sum(xi)

Tags: statistics

What is $$E\left[\frac{n}{\sum_i^nx_{i}}\right]$$

where $X_i\sim N\Big(\frac{1}{\theta}, 1\Big)$

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: If this is in connection to your [last question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3862172/321264), please edit the old post to share your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if your really have to calculate this expectation....but reading the title, if you are only interested in detecting if your MLE is unbiased, the answer is the following

By Jensen's inequality

$$E[\frac{n}{\sum_{i=1}^nx_i}]\ne\frac{n}{\sum_{i=1}^nE[x]}=\theta$$

Thus  your MLE is biased

Comment: I tried to put instead $$E[\frac{1}{mean(x)}]$$

Comment: @AKS : I edited my answer. I do not know the text of your problem but perhaps this answer can help you...